# Unable to set the click event for 2 images in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two images with the title "Show Options" it looks like this:

```
<a class="io-content-pane-header-button-right" style="right: 41px;"><img class="io-content-pane-header-button" src="/document/c947bf0e-0144-4fc8-8a33-ce0d0d698384/latest" title="Show Options"></a>
```

I have the following jQuery to display another div called "recordViewPopover" when this image is clicked.

```
$('img[title*=\"Show\"]').live('click', function(e) {
    console.log('RECORD VIEW OPTION SELECTED!');
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();      
    var position = $(this).parent().offset(); 
    $('#recordViewPopover').css('top', (position.top + $(this).height()) - 50);
    console.log(position);
    $('#recordViewPopover').fadeToggle('fast');
    if ($('img[title*=\"Show\"]').hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $('img[title*=\"Show\"]').addClass('active');
    }
  });
```

The problem is, I want to be able to show another DIV called "objectViewPopover" when the 2nd image is clicked. Right now, when I click on the 2nd image, only "recordViewPopover" is shown.

How can I solve this?

UPDATE:

here is a simpler scenario, I am just going through each of the images:

```
$('img[title*=\"Show\"]').each(function(index, value){
    if(index === 0){
        console.log('object');
        $(this).live('click', function(e) {

            console.log('OBJECT VIEW OPTION SELECTED!');

        });
    }
    else
        console.log('record');
  });
```

Why doesn't the click bind to the first match?

Comment: Never mind the last comment. You just want us to write something for you?

Comment: I'm pretty new to jQuery, just wondering how I can get it to match the 2nd image, so I can display the div properly. This current code displays my div, just don't know how to wire it up to the 2nd image so that I can display a different div, they seem to conflict cuz of the name "Show Options"

Comment: You could just give them each a different id.

Comment: Is there a way to do it, where I don't have to give it a different id? I don't control that, and the code should be robust enough to get the 2nd image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the positioning of the images in the DOM is consistent you could do something like

```
if($(this).is(':last-child'))...
```

Or you could give the images a unique class:

```
<a class="io-content-pane-header-button-right recordView" style="right: 41px;"><img class="io-content-pane-header-button" src="/some/src" title="Show Options"></a>

<a class="io-content-pane-header-button-right objectView" style="right: 41px;"><img class="io-content-pane-header-button" src="/some/other/src" title="Show Options"></a>
```

and do

```
if($(this).hasClass('objectView'))...
```

Comment: I tried the :last-child method and also comparing .last() but I get the same results as in my original question.

Comment: Did you try the `hasClass()` logic?

Comment: I unfortunately don't have control of how the front-end is being presented to me. I have to work with the constraints that I have presented, so I can't use hasClass in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In the images add data attribute, something like this

```
First Image: <img class="io-content-pane-header-button" data-divid="recordViewPopover"...> 

Second Image: <img class="io-content-pane-header-button" data-divid="objectViewPopover"...>
```

and change

```
$('#recordViewPopover')
```

to

```
$('#' + $(this).data("divid"))
```

and change

```
$('img[title*=\"Show\"]')
```

to

```
$(this)
```

in your code.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6yppw/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
img1=$('img[title*=\"Show\"]')[0];
img2=$('img[title*=\"Show\"]')[1];
$(img1).live('click', function(e) {
    console.log('RECORD VIEW OPTION SELECTED!');
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();      
    var position = $(this).parent().offset(); 
    $('#recordViewPopover').css('top', (position.top + $(this).height()) - 50);
    console.log(position);
    $('#recordViewPopover').fadeToggle('fast');
    if ($(img1).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $(img1).addClass('active');
    }
  });



  $(img2).live('click', function(e) {
    console.log('OBJECT VIEW OPTION SELECTED!');
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();      
    var position = $(this).parent().offset(); 
    $('objectViewPopover').css('top', (position.top + $(this).height()) - 50);
    console.log(position);
    $('objectViewPopover').fadeToggle('fast');
    if ($(img2).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $(img2).addClass('active');
    }
  });
```

I'm not great with jQuery, but try that.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Same results as the code in my question.

Comment: Odd, I would assume that to work, but now none of them do anything. the console.log doesn't trigger.

Comment: @SheehanAlam, Sorry, I really don't know what's up then.

Comment: Is there any way you can provide a jsfiddle for this or link us to your page?